# Запись через fwrite дает лишние 4 символа в конце

Tags: c++

Задача в том, чтобы считать последние 64кб файла. Если файл весит меньше, то считать его полностью, а потом перезаписать по пути W:\Test.txt. Но беда в том, что после записи в конце файла я получаю лишние символы. Если открыть обычным блокнотом, то это 4 буквы "Н", если через Notepad++, то это вот что — «ออออ».
Что я делаю не так?

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    char filename [5000];

    cout << "Hi! Enter the filename:";
    gets_s(filename);

    errno_t err;

    FILE *pFile;
    err = fopen_s(&pFile, filename, "r");

    long long nFileLen = 0;
    long long offset = 0;
    long long postfix = 65536;
    char * buffer;
    if (pFile)
    {
        fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
        nFileLen = ftell(pFile);
        if ((nFileLen - 65536) < 0) postfix = nFileLen;
        offset = nFileLen - postfix; 
        fseek(pFile, offset, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * postfix);
        fread(buffer,1,nFileLen,pFile);
        fclose(pFile);
    }
    cout << sizeof(buffer);
    FILE *File;
    err = fopen_s(&File, "W:\Test.txt","wb");
    fwrite(buffer, 1, postfix, File);
    fclose(File);
}
```

UPD: Выяснил, что эти символы добавляются в замен символу перевода каретки - `\r`.
То есть, символы перевода каретки игнорируются, а в замен их дописываются какие-то левые данные.

Comment: попробуйте rb режим. Потренируйтесь на файле с двумя байтами: 0d 0a. sizeof(buffer) возвращает размер указателя, а не данных. добавьте else для pFile == nullptr. `offset = max(nFileLen-postfix, 0);`

Comment: Что-то много странностей в коде... Почему `fread` пытается читать `nFileLen` байтов, когда ясно, что в общем случае `nFileLen` байтов там не осталось, а осталось только `postfix` байтов? (Да и память вы выделяете ровно для `postfix` байтов.) В чем смысл `cout << sizeof(buffer);`? Почему запись результата не попала под `if (pFile)`?

Answer (score 0):

Пока ждал подсказки от гуру, разобрался сам. Дело в том, что я открывал файл на чтение как текстовый(с флагом "r"), а нужно было как двоичный("rb"). То есть, нужно исправить  `err = fopen_s(&pFile, filename, "r");` на  `err = fopen_s(&pFile, filename, "rb");`